# Cannot add comments to wordpress using php

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I am trying to add comments to my wordpress site using this code.
But it stops after "'author' =>" and then it shows the code what comes after it.

```
 <? 
  include("IXR_Library.php.inc"); 
  $client = new IXR_Client("http://ajax1.nl/xmlrpc.php"); 

  $time = date("Ymd")."T".date("H:i:s")."Z";
  $post_id = 57891; 
  $data = array('author' => 'Username','content' => 'Testcomment','date' =>     $time,'author_email' => 'someone@something.com','approved' => 1);  

  if (!$client->query("wp.newComment","", "","",$post_id, $data)) 
  { 
   die("An error occurred - ".$client->getErrorCode().":".$client->getErrorMessage());
  } 
  $result = $client->wp_insert_comment($data); 
  print($result); 
 ?>
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1):

You should take away that last `,` in the `$data` array.

eg

```
$data = array('author' => 'Username','content' => 'Testcomment','date' => $time,'author_email' => 'someone@something.com','approved' => 1);
```

Also `$time` is going into a column called `date`. `date` is reserved in mysql ([source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)).

Think about changing the column name.